# Reordering 26 letters, probability of certain outcomes

Tags: permutations, independence

My problem is based on the random ordering the letters of the alphabet `{A, B, C, ... X, Y, Z}`

It asks me to find the probability that A is placed to the left of C as well as the probability that both A and B are to the left of C.

I know the there are `26!` possible orderings of the letters. I know the 2nd probability is going to be the intersection of two symmetric events. The part I am having trouble with is defining the numerators for both of these events. Anybody have any strategies for approaching this kind of problem?

Comment: Hint:  use symmetry,  How should the probability that $A<C$ compare to the probability that $C<A$?

Comment: @lulu I think those probabilities should be equal, as would be the probability of `B < C`.

Comment: Well, for the first problem you just need $A<C$ and $C<A$.  So what does that symmetry imply for your first problem?

Comment: You can, if you choose, keep track of all twenty six letters, in which case there are indeed $26!$ different equally likely possibilities.  A *much easier* approach is to ignore every letter's existence except those that matter, giving only two possibilities for the first problem and only six possibilities for the second problem, a much easier to work with denominator.  The point is to recognize that those two possibilities in the first and those six possibilities in the second are in fact equally likely in their respective scenarios.

Comment: If you insist on keeping track of all twenty six letters, you can count the number of arrangements in the following way:  First pick the locations occupied by the two (or three) important letters.  Then in the remaining $24$ (or $23$) locations, arrange the remaining letters.  Finally pick how the important letters are arranged within their designated spaces so they satisfy our desired conditions.  For the first problem this gives $\frac{\binom{26}{2}24!}{26!}$ which simplifies considerably.

Comment: So for the two problems I can imagine a denominators `choose(26, 2)` and `choose(26, 3)`  since the problem is essentially the assignment of numbers to the letters of interest. What I can't seem to reconcile is how to capture each instance in which `A < C`. I know each letter has a `1/26` probability of being in any of the positions. I don't know how I can use this symmetry to compare these positions

Comment: @JMoravitz your edits help a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct that the probability of $A$ occurring to the left of $C$
is $\frac 12$, by symmetry. More specifically, the sample space,consisting of orderings of the alphabet, breaks into two mutually exclusive events : one in which $A$ comes before $C$, and one in which it comes after. These events can be put in bijective correspondence via switching $A$ and $C$, and now the ordinary formula for probability gives the result.

For the second situation, something similar applies, but with a lot more events. Consider just three letters, $A,B$ and $C$. Amongst each other, there are six ways to arrange these letters :
$$
ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA
$$

Now, we have some other letters $D , ..., Z$ which we can insert into the given $A-B-C$ strings, to give an ordering of the alphabet. But, this is the key point : *the event that we want to study, involves only the positions of $A,B,C$ with respect to each other. This allows us to ignore the positions of the other letters, and therefore study in essence, a smaller problem*. The smaller problem? Well, when do both $A$ and $B$ lie to the left of $C$? And the answer is given above : it happens precisely $\frac 16$ of the time.

Now, let us formally write this. Create the following subsets of the sample space : $S_{ABC} = \{o : \text{In $o$, the letters $A,B,C$ occur in the order ABC, maybe not consecutively}\}$.

Now, we can go on and define $S_{ACB}, S_{BAC}$ etc. and get six different sets. We will let $S_{xyz}$ denote any of the six sets above i.e. $x,y,z$ is some permutation of $A,B,C$.

- It is clear that the $S_{xyz}$ are disjoint, since $ABC$ cannot occur in two different orders in the same permutation. However, it must occur in some order. This gives, that the sample space is a disjoint union of the $S_{xyz}$.
- Next, there is a bijection between $S_{xyz}$ and $S_{x'y'z'}$ : take any order, and switch only $x,y,z$ amongst themselves so that the order becomes a member of $S_{x'y'z'}$. This is a bijection.

So, the break up of our sample space into six disjoint equiprobable events is complete. We desire the probability of one of these events, $S_{ABC}$ and hence the solution is $\frac 16$.

Comment: Thank you! This is an excellent explanation!!

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, this would qualify for as good a  solution, as if you were to do it by "counting" the favourable events.